# Yahoo Contact Import Not Works

Tags: php, yahoo, yahoo-api

I am trying to get my guid in order to get yahoo contacts into my web site.

URL - http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid

Above URL is used to get the guid for the logged yahoo user but url returns

I have following things to get contact import from Yahoo
1. Consumer Key

2. Consumer Secret
3. Oauth Token
4. Oauth Secret

I believe - in resent yahoo contact import not works. please guide me how to import yahoo contacts.

[image]

Comment: That message sounds like they've got an outage.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "http" in http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user with "https" and all ports from 80 to 443. This will work.